# Region names in English cause surprise

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017

<strike>I'm a substance used to increase glossiness. Or, if you prefer, a really thick stick.</strike>

I'm Polish. Or, if you prefer, a Pole. For some reason, really weird things happen when you try to bring anything related to Poland into English.

For instance, this really caught me off-guard:

[image: picture of the survey, with 15 out of 16 voivodeship translated]

About half of provinces are directly translated to English, about half are named after their capital cities, one is in Polish (*Podlaskie*), one is named after a Polish name weird (*Lubusz*) and then there's *Holy Cross Province*.

I mean, *Holy Cross Province*. Oh my goodness, *Holy Cross Province*. I laughed at that for several minutes.

I guess these *are* official translations, but this is literally the first time I've seen them all listed (*Holy Cross Province*, heh), and I was confused for quite a while. I was really surprised you didn't use Polish names.

Is it common for names of regions of other countries to be translated like that? *Should* they be translated?

Are there any other Poles who will tell me that's nothing weird and I'm just being anti-social rube living under a rock as usual?

Comment: French region names weren't translated. ("Pays de la Loire", "Nouvelle-Aquitaine", "Hauts-de-France", ...) I don't think they should be translated.

Comment: That's always the issue with local names which also have names in other languages… Is it *"Rhineland-Palatinate"*, which I don't think any German has ever heard of, or *Rheinland-Pfalz* (oh, *that!*). I'd agree that the local name should be fine. If you're from there, you'll know it by that name best. Even if you're a foreigner living there, you'll know it by that name.

Comment: I guess somebody... *[puts on sunglasses]* ... tripped up. *YYYEEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHH!*

Comment: Wikipedia knows the name "Holy Cross Province", as do many other websites listed on Google, so it doesn't seem nearly as absurd or comical as you make it out to be. But I do agree that it is odd to translate region names into English, and that it would be better just to use the official names in the official language.

Comment: I'm from Holland.  Or, if you prefer, a Hole.  We call your country "Polen", a region like Pomorze is "Pommeren", its unpronounceable Szczecin is "Stettin", etc.  We insult the French by naming it "Parijs", tick off the Brits by misspelling it "Londen", etc.  Nothing for Województwo świętokrzyskie, we didn't go there it seems.

Comment: @Will: I don't get it

Comment: On my survey, they just had a text box.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_Poland

Comment: I assure everyone my comment was both clever and funny. Explaining it will ruin this, so I'll just leave it there.

Comment: I second that; this does sound extremely counter-intuitive to find my province on that list. I suppose the international-used names should stay there (like, for foreigners living in Poland), but I'd personally opt for including both native and english names, to make it easier for both natives and foreigners. "Holy Cross Province"...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Are you unfamiliar with [(•_•) / ( •_•)>⌐■-■ / (⌐■_■)](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/puts-on-sunglasses-yeeeeaaahhh)?

Comment: "Is it common for names of regions of other countries to be translated like that?"  Yes.  Being a (former) colonial power we liked to rename most countries, regions and cities.  It started off with just the ones we took over but extended to everywhere we ever heard of.  If we call it Germany instead of Deutschland we may as well rename any other notable geographical item too.  

"Should they be translated?" If you are viewing them in (British) English and there is a translation for them then yes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: No, but where does "tripping" come into it?

Comment: I think it is bad idea to try to translate such local names. If all regions can be normally translated - ok. But if some cannot be translated or half-translated (1 of words) then it is better to keep local names.

Comment: As a foreigner living in Poland I support this as well. I'd have to *reverse translate* "Holy Cross Province" in order to figure out if that's the province I'm living in, if I were living in that province. The point is that the local names should be used, because that's what we see everywhere. There aren't any english translations on the boards around.

Comment: As @NullReference said, the solution is very simple: include BOTH the local name and the English translation!

Comment: @TafT I don't think it has anything to do with being a colonial power. My country, Czech Republic, was never any kind of power, and we rename everything anyway. It's not Wrocław, it's Vratislav. It's not London, but Londýn. It's not Paris, it's Paříž (which only Czechs can pronounce). It's not Deutschland, it's Německo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Only has local names, at the moment]
This appears to have been changed since then, and it's a lot more intuitive *to me*, can't tell for foreigners in Poland. That was swift!